# Google analytics problems after play services upgrade to 7.5

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

After we upgraded Google Play Services to:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
```

Note that [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/app?configured=true) say we have to use play-services-analytics:7.3.0,
however since we are using play services 7.5, we have used the configurations stated at the start.

The app compiles fine but we've noticed our Google Analytics no longer send to our server. And also whenever we make call Tracker.send() the following lines will appear in the error log per event:

```
06-30 10:51:43.188  13623-13752/com.fairfax.domain E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1032) statement aborts at 31: [INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO properties(cid,app_uid,hits_count,adid,params,tid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]
06-30 10:51:43.198  13623-13752/com.fairfax.domain E/GAv4﹕ Error storing a property: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
06-30 10:51:44.348  13623-13752/com.fairfax.domain E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1032) statement aborts at 31: [INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO properties(cid,app_uid,hits_count,adid,params,tid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]
06-30 10:51:44.358  13623-13752/com.fairfax.domain E/GAv4﹕ Error storing a property: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
06-3
```

We proxied the traffic and saw that indeed it did not seem to send the GA events.

As a workaround for now we made the change to manual dispatching:

```
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(0);
```

and manually calling:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(appContext).dispatchLocalHits();
```

But of course this is less than ideal, how would we let Google Analytics Handle storing/sending based on configurations and not get the errors?

UPD: It is probably worth mentioning that we're upgrading from play services 6.5.

UPD2: We proxied network again and now it appears that GA does send /batch request after a while. Those SQLite errors are still present though:

```
8273-8329/com.fairfax.domain E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1032) statement aborts at 29: [INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO properties(cid,app_uid,hits_count,adid,params,tid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)]
```

Comment: If it worked before you upgraded seams strange it doesn't work after the upgrade. I cant help with Android but I emailed the Analytics SDK team for you just incase its their bug.

Comment: @DaImTo those SQLite errors seem to disappear after the device is rebooted. Everything works as expected after that. Having said that, we're still hesitant to release a build with 7.5 play services since we can't expect users to reboot their devices that frequently.

Comment: Did you any find solution for it?

Comment: @SagarTrehan we upgraded to 8.3.0 which was published recently. I don't recall seeing the error since.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. I will try by updating play services version

Answer (score 0):

Is SQLiteLog a class you wrote or Google Analytics provides? If you're using a DBHelper you could try getWritableDatabase() on it.

Do you have any long running services that might be using the old database, or have some lock in it?

You could also try bumping your build number on the app, and looking into a SQL migration.